# What does it mean when an array is used to index an array in python?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a snippit of code as follows:

```
    y = np.array(self.unique_y)
    random_indices = self.random_generator.integers(0,len(self.unique_y), size=5)
    return y[random_indices]
```

`unique_y` is simply an 1D array of [0 1 2].

My understanding of `integers` is that it produces an array, which is confirmed when I printed `y` and `random_indices.`

Here, `y` is [0 1 2] and `random_indices` is [2 2 1 0 2].
The return is also [2 2 1 0 2]

My two questions:

1. Can I just do

```
    return np.array(self.random_generator.integers(0,len(self.unique_y), size=5))
```

2. What is it doing using `random_indices` to index `y` in `y[random_indices]`?  Both `y` and `random_indices` are arrays but one is used to index the other.

Comment: This behaviour is Numpy specific and you should read an introduction to Numpy in order to understand it.

Comment: Which section of the Numpy documentation contains this? I have already read the indexing section but it did not contain any examples of using an array to index another array.

Comment: `self.random_generator.integers(0,len(self.unique_y), size=5)` is already a numpy array.  There's no need to wrap in in the `np.array` call again.  And it doesn't do anything with `y`.

Comment: Have you really read the index completely? [Integer array indexing](https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/basics.indexing.html#integer-array-indexing)

Answer (score 0):

Make a 1d array:

```
In [337]: y = np.arange(10)*10    
In [338]: y
Out[338]: array([ 0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90])
```

and other array with values in the correct range (0 to 10):

```
In [339]: idx = np.array([2,5,0])
```

Simply select the corresponding elements from `y`:

```
In [340]: y[idx]
Out[340]: array([20, 50,  0])
```

That works if `idx` is a list as well.

Things become more complicated when `y` has more dimensions, and we use arrays to index all dimensions.  For that you need to understand `broadcasting`.  But for 1d arrays, the indexing is straightforward.

The list equivalent is:

```
In [341]: [y[i] for i in idx]
Out[341]: [20, 50, 0]
```